# Neo4j: performance issue finding all paths between two nodes with CYPHER

Tags: path, neo4j, cypher

I'm using TheMovieDB database downloaded [here](http://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/). It has ~60k nodes and ~100k relationships and I need to find all the paths of a given length **k** between two nodes **a** and **b** with a given *name* property.
Let's say I need to find all the path of lenght 2 between *Keanu Reeves* and *Laurence Fishburne*. I used the following CYPHER query:

```
MATCH (k)-[e*2..2]-(l)
WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
RETURN k,e,l
```

and it took 40 seconds.

I decided to try a different approach and used the following query instead:

```
MATCH (k)--(m)--(l)
WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
RETURN k,m,l
```

and it took 252 milliseconds!

Those two queries gave the same results, had the same meaning and yet the first one took 200x more time. How is that possibile?

I need to conduct some tests in which I have to find all the paths with a given maximum (but not a minimum) length between two given nodes. This gives me some problems because I cannot use the second approach I described (it works only with a fixed lenght path) and the first one is waaaay too slow.

I also cannot use *allShortestPath* because it doesn't return any path whose length is greater than the shorter one.

It's driving me crazy...
Any idea how to solve it?

**Edit**

Another example of how big this issue is: finding a path of lenght 4 between *Robert Downey Jr.* and *Harrison Ford*.
Method #2: ~500 milliseconds
Method #1: >360 seconds (after those 6 minutes I brutally unplugged the pc power adaptor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your first query is taking so long is because it is not using any indexes at all; you are scanning the entire database.

If you change your query slightly to include the `Actor` label in the path you are matching you will significantly improve the query performance.

```
MATCH (k)-[e*2..2]-(l)
WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
RETURN k,e,l
```

If you reveal the indexes by executing the `:schema` command in the browser you will see the indexes that are in place.  You can see that the first one is on `:Actor(name)`; withing the `Actor` label the `name` property is indexed.

```
Indexes
  ON :Actor(name)    ONLINE                             
  ON :Director(name) ONLINE                             
  ON :Movie(title)   ONLINE                             
  ON :Person(name)   ONLINE                             
  ON :User(login)    ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
  ON (user:User) ASSERT user.login IS UNIQUE
```

If you `profile` your query

```
profile
MATCH (k)-[e*2..2]-(l)
WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
RETURN k,e,l
```

and then profile the one with the `:Actor` label added it will be abundantly clear why the two perform differently.

```
profile
MATCH (k:Actor)-[e*2..2]-(l:Actor)
WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
RETURN k,e,l
```

I forgot to add that you should also `profile` your second ( faster ) query:

```
profile
MATCH (k)--(m)--(l)
WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
RETURN k,m,l
```

You will see that the query plans are significantly different.  I think simply adding an asterisk to a relationship probably sends the database engine down a different optimization path.

Good luck!

Comment: Since the query
     MATCH p = allShortesPath((k)-[e*2..2]-(l))
     WHERE k.name = "Keanu Reeves" AND l.name = "Laurence Fishburne"
     RETURN k,e,l
worked like a charm, I thought Neo4j automatically had looked for some indexes by itself... my bad =)

I'm really thankful for your help!

Comment: @fgiacc Is there any function called "allShortestPath" in cypher ?